# Сбор комментариев к постам через execute API VK на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vkscript

Пытаюсь разобраться как работает execute, но как-то не поддается мне это.
Из БД я получаю список всех групп пользователя, перебираю их и получаю id постов групп так же из БД

```
user_id = xxx
groups_id = [i.group_id
             for i in session.query(Groups_user).filter(Groups_user.user_id == get_system_id(session, user_id)).all()]

for group_id in groups_id:
    group_post_id = [get_id_vk(session, i.post_group_id)
                     for i in session.query(Group_post).filter(Group_post.group_id == group_id).all()]
```

После получения id постов групп, нужно вызвать функцию execute для получения комментариев к данным постам, и как это сделать я абсолютно не понимаю. Я знаю как это сделать без execute но это занимает много времени. Ткните меня лицом в то как это должно быть.

Я нашел пример рабочего кода, но не могу его адаптировать под себя.

```
code = """return API.wall.get({
    "owner_id": "",
    "domain": "itmoru",
    "offset": 0,
    "count": 1,
    "filter": "owner",
    "extended": 0,
    "fields": "",
    "v": "5.126"
});"""

response = requests.post(
    url="https://api.vk.com/method/execute",
        data={
            "code": code,
            "access_token": "xxx",
            "v": "5.126"
        }
)
```

Пока стою написал только такой не рабочий код:

```
groups_id = [i.group_id
             for i in session.query(Groups_user).filter(Groups_user.user_id == get_system_id(session, user_id)).all()]

for group_id in groups_id:
    group_post_id = [get_id_vk(session, i.post_group_id)
                     for i in session.query(Group_post).filter(Group_post.group_id == group_id).all()]
    for i in group_post_id:
        code = f"""return API.wall.getComments({
            "owner_id": "{group_id}",
            "count": 100,
            "post_id": "{i}",
            "v": "5.126"
        });"""

        response = requests.post(
            url="https://api.vk.com/method/execute",
                data={
                    "code": code,
                    "access_token": "xxx",
                    "v": "5.126"
                })
        ic(response.json())

ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

Comment: А весь код можно получить? Это какой-то кусок чего-то. Обычно говорят: Выкладывайте максимально воспроизводимый код, вот как из этого можно что-то запустить и проверить? Токины можете спрятать

Comment: Какой весь?  Я вам и дал весь код. Там же просто из БД я забираю значения

Comment: Ошибка в неправильном использовании f-string. У вас фигурные скобки в методе не экранируются. Должно быть примерно так: `f"return API.wall.getComments({{...}})"`.